# serial port close issue in node red

Tags: serial-port, node-red, johnny-five

i am using johnny-five and the problem is how to close the serial port which is already opend? 
the problem is when i re-deploy the code in the node red it throws an error as shown below:

```
    10 Feb 10:38:33 - [info] Stopping flows
    10 Feb 10:38:33 - [info] Stopped flows
    10 Feb 10:38:33 - [info] Starting flows
    1518239313152 Connected COM6
    10 Feb 10:38:33 - [info] Started flows
    1518239313157 Error Opening COM6: Access denied
    (node:12788) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Unhandled "error" event. ([object Object])
    (node:12788) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    1518239323160 Device or Firmware Error A timeout occurred while connecting to the Board.
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is probably to set Deploy to "Modified Nodes Only" so Node-RED will only restart the johnny-five if it has been changed.

You will have to raise an issue with the developer of the johnny-five node ([node-red-contrib-gpio](https://github.com/monteslu/node-red-contrib-gpio)?)to get this fixed properly.